# How to read some layers inside the folder and match with others in another folder with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I did a little program in PyQGIS, but this just compares the first raster layer inside a folder with all the vector layers inside a folder. I want to match one raster layer with one vector layer. Someone please help me. This is my program. That select 4 pixels of a raster layer around a point in the vector layer.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# Author: Blanca Rios
# Purpouse: Extract by mask TOTAL
# ---------------------------------------------------------

# Import system modules
import os, sys, glob
import numpy
import pickle
date=['2003']
for x in date:
# Arguments
    points = "C:/Users/IMMWIN1/Documents/viento/dire_FRE/"+x+"/points"
    rasters = "D:/MYD04/"+x+"/AODSN"

    #for data in os.listdir(rasters):
      #            if data.endswith(".tif"):
        #              rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(rasters+ "/" + data, data)
          #            rprovider = rlayer.dataProvider()
                      #print rprovider
            #          xsize = rlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
                      #print xsize
              #        ysize = rlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
                      #print ysize
      # load vector layers
    capa=[]

    for files in os.listdir(points):
            # load only the shapefiles
                 punto=[]
                 if data.endswith(".tif"):
                     rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(rasters+ "/" + data, data)
                     rprovider = rlayer.dataProvider()
                     print rprovider
                     xsize = rlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
                     print xsize
                     ysize = rlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
                 if files.endswith(".shp"):
                     vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(points+ "/" + files, files, "ogr")
                     feat = vlayer.getFeatures()


                     for feature in feat:
    # retrieve every feature with its geometry and attributes
    # fetch geometry
                             attrs = feature.attributes()
                             #print attrs[1]
                             geom = feature.geometry()
                             #print "Feature ID %d: " % feature.id()

                             point = geom.asPoint()
                             if  attrs >= 0 and attrs <= 90:
    #pixel and its 8 surrounding pixels from points
                                 puntos = [ QgsPoint(point[0], point[1] + ysize ),
                                    QgsPoint(point[0] + xsize, point[1] + ysize ),
                                    point,
                                    QgsPoint(point[0] + xsize, point[1])]

                             elif attrs >= 91 and attrs <= 180:
                                 puntos = [point,
                                      QgsPoint(point[0] + xsize, point[1]),
                                      QgsPoint(point[0], point[1] - ysize ),
                                      QgsPoint(point[0] + xsize, point[1] - ysize) ]

                             elif attrs >= 181 and attrs <= 270:
                                 puntos = [QgsPoint(point[0] - xsize[j], point[1]),
                                      point,
                                      QgsPoint(point[0] - xsize, point[1] - ysize ),
                                      QgsPoint(point[0], point[1] - ysize )]

                             else :#attrs >= 271 and attrs <= 359:
                                 puntos = [ QgsPoint(point[0] - xsize, point[1] + ysize ),
                                      QgsPoint(point[0], point[1] + ysize ),
                                      QgsPoint(point[0] - xsize, point[1]),
                                      point]

                             valor=[]

                             for point in puntos:
                                   value =rprovider.identify(point, QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results()[1]
                                   valor.append(value)
                             punto.append(valor) 

                 capa.append(punto)
    print capa
numpy.savetxt("D:/MYD04/"+x+"/EXCEL/"+x+"prueba.txt", capa,delimiter=",",fmt='%s')


print "\n\t Process done!!"
```